# Optimize this LINQ Query

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am having performance issues with this LINQ Query.
The data is laoded into to this.students already.
Now when I call the GetStudentData function say 1000 times it has a huge overhead.
Is there a way of improving this without changing the LINQ to a loop

```
   public Student GetStudentData()
   {         
          IEnumerable<Students> studentTypes = this.students.Where(x => (x.studentsId  == studentId && x.StduentType.Equals(studentType)));
          if(studentTypes.Count==0) return new Student() { studentid=studentID};
          return (Student)studentTypes.First();
   }
```

So here are the results when looping through it 10000 times with my original version

Original Version : 5.6 seconds on the average
New Version @des's Code with `FirstOrDefault` : 3.6 seconds

Comment: Are you actually running this 1000? Otherwise, this post is pretty appropriate: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsYouArentSmarterThanTheCompilerPlusFunWithMicrobenchmarks.aspx

Comment: ew, as an aside, I really don't like how you're returning a new Student if none matching the criteria is found -very confusing.

Comment: yes i am running this 1000 times

Comment: Is `IEnumerable<Students>` a typo? Should it be `IEnumerable<Student>`?

Comment: yes that must be a typo.Sorry

Comment: Then what's the purpose of the cast (in the return statement)? You are redundantly casting a `Student` to `Student`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `studentTypes.Count` actually be `studentTypes.Count()`?

Comment: And I'm guessing `StduentType` should be `StudentType`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Where` you loop through **all** records which fulfill given conditions, when you use `First` you just search for **first** record which fullfills condition, so using `First` should speed it up.

```
public Student GetStudentData()
{         
    // get first student by id and type, return null if there is no such student
    var student = students.FirstOrDefault(i => i.studentsId == studentId && i.StudentType.Equals(studentType));

    // if student is null then return new student
    return student ?? new Student();
}
```

Comment: that might simplify the code, but there's no optimization there

Comment: @ErOx check my updated answer, `First` should be faster than `Where` because it won't check all records...

Comment: Good explanation...let me test and see the results

Comment: that's not right. why would you think there's a performance difference between .First(anonymous-delegate) and Where(anonymous-delegate).First()? Don't you think the *exact same* filter is being ran in both cases?

Comment: look at the IL, I can assure you it is

Comment: What about this: `var all = students.Where(i => i.studentsId == studentId && i.StudentType.Equals(studentType)); var first = all.First();`? Won't if firstly search all students with those conditions and then take first one?

Comment: sure, but my point is the same filter is being ran one way or the other, so there's really no optimization there. `First(x => x ...)` is simply a shorthand for `.Where(x => x ... ).First()`

Comment: @ErOx OP's code also contains `Count()` - which completely traverses the enumerator returned from `Where()`. And then `First()` traverses it **again** until the first element. Des's code does only one (and shorter!) traversal instead of two.

Comment: Example: you have a collection { "a", "b", "c" }, when you use `Where(i => i == "a")` you loop through whole collection (so you check "a", "b", "c"), whereas when you use `First(i => i == "a")` you'll only check first element of collection (because condition has been statisfied). Am I not right?

Comment: It did increase the performance.Let me add the results and modify my code as well....but can it be increased further

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663897/why-is-linq-wherepredicate-first-faster-than-firstpredicate# <--would suggest you did not see a performance benefit

Comment: @des, no that's not right. see the link to the question above

Comment: @ErOx this is interesting, I didn't know about that. I'll educate myself on this matter later. Perhaps I was wrong, but on the other hand abbas reported performance improvement. I'll test this whenever I'll have some spare time. Thank you for conversation ErOx.

Comment: no prob, you intuition is absolutely right to think it would be faster. indeed it is interesting that it's not faster

Comment: Erox but my results have improved.Is there any reson for that

Comment: I suspect you're benchmarking the entire method, in which case yes, you will see a performance benefit (because of the omission of the call to `.Count()`). if you benchmark *just* the change to the linq query, you won't see a performance benefit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...ur right i am benchmarking the entire method...but can you suggest any other way to optimize it

Comment: @abbas You are trying to fix the symptoms instead of fixing the root problem: using a data structure that is not well suited for the job. If you really care for performance, you'll have to consider a more substantial refactoring of your code.

Comment: The datasructure is a HashSet of students...as i mentioned before this is just a simpler version of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the issue is precisely the fact that you are calling this method in a loop, supposedly, 1000 times!

Why not changing the method to receive a list of studentIDs and return the 1000 students in one shot? Something like

```
var studentTypes = from c in this.students 
                   where studentIDs.Contains(c.StudentID)
                   select c;
```

Where studentIDs can be an `int[]` containing the list of student ids you want.

Comment: I think this is on the right track -looks like there needs to be some refactoring in the OP's logic

Comment: Nopes...This is called with different parameters...this is just a simpler version of the real function...so that its easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code so `this.students` is a `Dictionary<int, Student>` (key is `StudentId`), then reimplement your method similarly to this:

```
public Student GetStudentData(int studentId, StudentType studentType) {
    Student result;
    if (this.students.TryGetValue(studentId, out result))
        if (result.StudentType.Equals(studentType)))
            return result;
    return new Student { StudentId = studentId };
}
```

If you absolutely can't refactor `this.students`, you can always maintain the dictionary *in parallel*.

Or, you can simply create a temporary dictionary (`this.students.ToDictionary(student => student.StudentId)`) just before the 1000-iteration loop.