# Difference between using .First() and .Where().First()

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any difference between this:

`myList.Where(item => item == 0).First();`

and this:

`myList.First(item => item == 0);`

The later makes far more sense to me as it is shorter, but I seem to see the top version more often.

Comment: The Where is redundant and if you have ReSharper installed, it will suggest you the second form.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre-LucPineault ...seems someone is now saying using the later is more efficient...I can understand the reasoning, but everyone else says there is no difference!

Comment: you can do your own benchmarks if you want to test the efficiency. Get a huge list of items, call both methods millions of times and compare the execution time.

Comment: See [Why is LINQ .Where(predicate).First() faster than .First(predicate)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8663897/9664)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. If the LINQ is translating to a piece of SQL then it depends on how that translation is handled. If you are using LINQ to objects (e.g. you are looking at an existing in memory array) then, while the end result in the same, the performance is markedly different. I ran some bench marks and was actually surprised at the result. I would have assumed that `array.First()` would be more efficient than `array.Where(...).First()`, but I found it to be the other way around.

I created a test, and to see how long it would take to traverse the array, I put the search item the last on the array. I did 200 tests of each, each test consisting of 1000 iterations. The average result, in Ticks, was:

```
First()         = 2655969
Where().First() = 1455211
```

As you can see `Where().First()` takes roughly about half the time of `First()` alone.

My benchmarking application is as follows:

```
class Program
{
  private const int internalIterations = 1000;
  private const int externalIterations = 100;
  private const int dataSize = 100000;
  private const int search = dataSize - 1;

  private static readonly long[] resultsFirst = new long[externalIterations*2];
  private static readonly long[] resultsWhereFirst = new long[externalIterations*2];
  private static readonly int[] data = Enumerable.Range(0, dataSize).ToArray();

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    for (int i = 0; i < externalIterations; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Iteration {0} of {1}", i+1, externalIterations);
      sw.Restart();
      First();
      sw.Stop();
      resultsFirst[i*2] = sw.ElapsedTicks;
      Console.WriteLine("     First : {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);

      sw.Restart();
      WhereFirst();
      sw.Stop();
      resultsWhereFirst[i*2] = sw.ElapsedTicks;
      Console.WriteLine("WhereFirst : {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);

      sw.Restart();
      WhereFirst();
      sw.Stop();
      resultsWhereFirst[(i*2)+1] = sw.ElapsedTicks;
      Console.WriteLine("WhereFirst : {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);

      sw.Restart();
      First();
      sw.Stop();
      resultsFirst[(i*2)+1] = sw.ElapsedTicks;
      Console.WriteLine("     First : {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    Console.WriteLine("Averages:");
    Console.WriteLine("     First Average: {0:0.00}", resultsFirst.Average());
    Console.WriteLine("WhereFirst Average: {0:0.00}", resultsWhereFirst.Average());

  }

  private static void WhereFirst()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < internalIterations; i++)
    {
      int item = data.Where(d => d == search).First();
    }
  }

  private static void First()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < internalIterations; i++)
    {
      int item = data.First(d => d == search);
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

I tried using a List instead of an array as the source of the data and found that it was slower.

The data creation line looks like this:

```
private static readonly List<int> data = Enumerable.Range(0, dataSize).ToList();
```

And the end result was:

```
First()         = 3222609
Where().First() = 2124652
```

Comment: Tested in .NET 7 and found that the difference seems even greater, where `Where().First()` is consistently about 4 times faster than `First()`.

Answer (score 5):

there is no difference other than style preference

Comment: Yes there is a small performance difference, but not one that will drastically impact a majority of implementation scenarios. This would only play out in edge cases. Still good information to understand how things work.

Answer (score 4):

`Where` does special optimizations for different kind of collection types, whereas other methods like `First`, `Single` and `Count` do not take advantage of the type of the collection.

So `Where(predicate).First()` is able to do some optimizations that `First(predicate)` doesn't.

To be honest, it is bad implementation.

Answer (score 2):

"Probably not" - It may depend if the Linq query incurs translation into another language or not - SQL, for example

Comment: This is a good point. linq2objects will have the same behavior, but linq2sql, linq2EF, linq2[x] may behave differently.

Comment: They should all "behave" the same. It is just the implementation that will be different.

Answer (score -3):

Functionally, they are the same, however, using `.First(...)` alone may be more efficient.

- `.Where(item => item == 0)` will scan the entire list of items and collect all items that match the criteria into a list.  Applying `.First()` on that list will select the first item.
- `.First(item => item == 0)` has the possibility of scanning the list until it finds the first match and stopping then once it finds the first match.

So using `.First(item => item == 0)` may end up being more efficient.

Comment: that is not correct. linq uses enumerations and deferred execution. so where(x).first() and first(x) will process the same number of items until 1 is found

Comment: "may end up being more efficient" is rather suggestive. Run some benchmarks and you may be surprised.

Comment: As mentioned above, [.Where(...).First() is faster than just .First(...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663897/why-is-linq-wherepredicate-first-faster-than-firstpredicate). Wow.

Comment: The only time it "collect[s] all items that match the criteria into a list" is if you put `.ToList()` on the end.

Answer (score -5):

.First() will iterate your list until it finds your item.
.Where() will iterate your whole list.

So using .First() should be more efficient. Unless if your compiler is smart enough to just do the First().