# What does "Replace with single call to single" mean?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When using LINQ with Single() I always get my line of code underlined in green with the suggestion "Replace with single call to single." What does this mean? Here's an example of a line of code that results in that suggestion:

```
var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == userID).Single();
```

As you can see I'm only using Single() once. So... what's the deal?

Comment: I wonder if that's something that should be fixed, since it's not more efficient: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663897/why-is-linq-wherepredicate-first-faster-than-firstpredicate

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I assume it means, use the [overload of `Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx) which takes a predicate instead of using `Where` and `Single` together:

```
var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.UserID == userID);
```

Comment: Nice! This also helped me when ReSharper gave a similar suggestion regarding FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 9):

```
var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.UserID == userID)
```

Syntactic sugar

Answer (score 5):

A bunch of the Linq expressions, [Enumerable Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), work this way, like the method **Single**, which takes a predicate and returns a true only if the condition is satisfied (test passed), otherwise a false.

These should be used instead of a Where() and Single() together:

```
var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.UserID == userID); 
// Checks for if there is one and, only one element that satisfy the condition.
```

and

```
var user = db.Users.Any(u => u.UserID == userID);  
// Checks for if there are any elements that satisfy the condition.
```

and

```
var user = db.Users.All(u => u.UserID == userID);  
// Checks if all elements satisfy the condition.
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from  where field in (list, of,field) can be implemented in Linq Lambda using two approaches

1. Using "Contains"
2. Using "Join"

Code sample [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j4vIzQ) in DotNetFiddle

[image]

```
using System;
 using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    //Initializing a collection of 4 Employees fromthree Different departments <Name of Employee, Dept ID>
    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> EmployeeDept = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> {
        new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("Gates",2),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("Nadella",2),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("Mark",3),
        new KeyValuePair<string, int> ("Pichai",4)
    };

    //Filter the Employees belongs to these department
    int[] deptToFilter ={3,4};

    //Approach 1 - Using COntains Method
    Console.WriteLine ("Approach 1 - Using Contains");
    Console.WriteLine ("==========================================");   
    var filterdByContains = EmployeeDept.Where(emp => deptToFilter.Contains(emp.Value));
    foreach (var dept3and4employees in filterdByContains)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dept3and4employees.Key+" - "+dept3and4employees.Value);
    }

    //Approach 2 Using Join
    Console.WriteLine ("\n\nApproach 2 - Using Join");
    Console.WriteLine ("==========================================");   
    var filteredByJoin = EmployeeDept.Join(
        deptToFilter,
        empdept => empdept.Value, 
        filterdept => filterdept, 
        (empdep,filddep) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(empdep.Key, empdep.Value)
    );

    foreach (var dept3and4employees in filteredByJoin)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dept3and4employees.Key+" - "+dept3and4employees.Value);
    }

}
}
```