# c# Linq to Objects - FirstOrDefault performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq

We're trying to optimize some of our methods. We use Redgate's Performance profiler to find some performance leaks.

Our tool uses Linq to objects in several methods. But we have noticed that a `FirstOrDefault` takes very long on collections with +/- 1000 objects.

The profiler also alerts that the query is very slow. I've added images with the profiler results.

It's not possible to add the collection to a database and then query the database.
Any recommendations?

Thanks !

```
private SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel GetParentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel(SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel saldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel, SaldoGebouwRekeningBoeking boeking, int privatiefKlant)
{
    SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel parentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel = null;

    if (saldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel != null)
    {
        try
        {
            parentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel = saldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel.AfrekenPeriode.SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutelCollection
                .FirstOrDefault(s => (boeking == null || (s.SaldoVerdeelsleutel != null &&
                (s.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID == boeking.SaldoGebouwRekeningVerdeling.SaldoGebouwRekening.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID)))
                && s.PrivatiefKlant.ID == privatiefKlant);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }

    return parentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel;
}
```

Image :
[Profile report](http://s13.postimg.org/z9uoojcxj/LINQ1.png)

Comment: My first thought is to move the `boeking == null` check, and the `SaldoGebouwRekeningVerdeling.SaldoGebouwRekening.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID` value _outside_ your loop. There's no reason to re-evaluate it for every single element in your collection.

Comment: The query is executed when you read from the expression. In this case the FirstOrDefault will execute the whole expression tree, so it's not the FirstOrDefault thats slow.

Comment: Obligatory remark: An empty `catch{}` is very harmful, remove it.

Comment: Now I'll ask you a question... That objects are loaded through NHibernate or Entity Framework, right? Are you sure they aren't partially LAZILY LOADED? Like this `s.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID` ? Because it could be a classical [SELECT N+1 antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue).

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to speed it up by rewriting it as

```
saldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel.AfrekenPeriode.SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutelCollection
            .Where(s => (boeking == null || (s.SaldoVerdeelsleutel != null &&
                (s.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID == boeking.SaldoGebouwRekeningVerdeling.SaldoGebouwRekening.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID))) && s.PrivatiefKlant.ID == privatiefKlant)
            .FirstOrDefault()
```

See [Why is LINQ .Where(predicate).First() faster than .First(predicate)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663897/why-is-linq-wherepredicate-first-faster-than-firstpredicate) for why this is faster.

Answer (score 2):

`FirstOrDefault` do standard linear search over source collection and returns first element that matches a predicate. It's *O(n)*, so it's not surprising that it takes more time on bigger collections.

You can try following, but the gain won't be huge, because it's still *O(n)*.

```
private SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel GetParentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel(SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel saldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel, SaldoGebouwRekeningBoeking boeking, int privatiefKlant)
{
    SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel parentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel = null;

    if (saldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var query = saldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel.AfrekenPeriode
                                                         .SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutelCollection
                                                         .Where(s => s.PrivatiefKlant.ID == privatiefKlant);

            if(boeking != null)
            {
                var gebouwVerdeelSleutelId = boeking.SaldoGebouwRekeningVerdeling
                                                    .SaldoGebouwRekening
                                                    .SaldoVerdeelsleutel
                                                    .GebouwVerdeelSleutel
                                                    .ID;

                query = query.Where(s => s.SaldoVerdeelsleutel != null &&
                    s.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID == gebouwVerdeelSleutelId);
            }
            parentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel = query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }

    return parentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel;
}
```

It will make better, because `boeking != null` check will be done only once, not on every source collection element. And because [nested `Where` calls are combined](http://mjuraszek.blogspot.com/2013/08/did-you-know-about-that-linq-feature-i.html) they will not cause performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

I'll say that this

```
boeking.SaldoGebouwRekeningVerdeling.SaldoGebouwRekening.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID
```

could be the culprit. Try caching it outside, like:

```
var id = boeking != null ? boeking.SaldoGebouwRekeningVerdeling.SaldoGebouwRekening.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID : 0;
```

and use the `id` inside the query.

(I'm doing a supposition: one of the properties of that long chain do something "not too much smart" and is in fact quite slow)

Answer (score 0):

You can try write it like a simple code. LINQ is using delegates this is why there is a little perfomance hit.

```
                try
                {
                    parentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel = null;
                    foreach (var s in saldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel.AfrekenPeriode.SaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutelCollection)
                    {
                        if ((boeking == null || (s.SaldoVerdeelsleutel != null && (s.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID == boeking.SaldoGebouwRekeningVerdeling.SaldoGebouwRekening.SaldoVerdeelsleutel.GebouwVerdeelSleutel.ID))) && s.PrivatiefKlant.ID == privatiefKlant)
                        {
                            parentSaldoPrivatiefKlantVerdeelsleutel = s;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
```